# Unfortunately App has Stopped while sending data to an Email in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am making an app in which i am allowing user to fill the form and sending those entered details to an email id

whenever i do click on Send Details button everytime i am getting : **Unfortunately Message Launcher has Stopped**

*Java Code:*

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form);




    Button mImgViewCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendFeedback);
    mImgViewCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {


    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();

    final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
    String email = emailField.getText().toString();

    final EditText feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
    String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();

    final Spinner feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);
    String feedbackType = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


    final CheckBox responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
    boolean bRequiresResponse = responseCheckbox.isChecked();

    // Take the fields and format the message contents
    String subject = formatFeedbackSubject(feedbackType);

    String message = formatFeedbackMessage(feedbackType, name,
         email, feedback, bRequiresResponse);

    // Create the message
    sendFeedbackMessage(subject, message);
   }

    });
}


protected String formatFeedbackSubject(String feedbackType) {

    String strFeedbackSubjectFormat = getResources().getString(
            R.string.feedbackmessagesubject_format);

    String strFeedbackSubject = String.format(strFeedbackSubjectFormat, feedbackType);

    return strFeedbackSubject;

}

protected String formatFeedbackMessage(String feedbackType, String name,
        String email, String feedback, boolean bRequiresResponse) {

    String strFeedbackFormatMsg = getResources().getString(
            R.string.feedbackmessagebody_format);

    String strRequiresResponse = getResponseString(bRequiresResponse);

    String strFeedbackMsg = String.format(strFeedbackFormatMsg,
            feedbackType, feedback, name, email, strRequiresResponse);

    return strFeedbackMsg;

}


protected String getResponseString(boolean bRequiresResponse)
{
    if(bRequiresResponse==true)
    {
        return getResources().getString(R.string.feedbackmessagebody_responseyes);
    } else {
        return getResources().getString(R.string.feedbackmessagebody_responseno);
    }

}

public void sendFeedbackMessage(String subject, String message) {

    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    String aEmailList[] = { "####@gmail.com" };
    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);

    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    messageIntent.setType("plain/text");
    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    startActivity(messageIntent);
}

   }
```

*form.xml:*

```
 <ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/feedbacktitle"
        android:textSize="10pt"></TextView>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/feedbackname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/feedbacktype"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"></Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/feedbackresponse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></CheckBox>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*Manifest.xml*

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jsrrestjjjb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.jsrrestjjjb.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
</manifest>
```

*Logcat:*

```
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  ... 11 more
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=plain/text flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at com.example.jsrrestjjjb.MainActivity.sendFeedbackMessage(MainActivity.java:102)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at com.example.jsrrestjjjb.MainActivity.sendFeedback(MainActivity.java:48)
01-05 10:02:12.759: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please post your java file code.

Comment: @Grishu posted java code, plz see above

Comment: Please post the code where onClick button call method to send e-mail

Comment: From where are you calling `onClick` method of button?

Comment: @Grishu buddy i have posted my new java code in which i am calling onClick method of button with xml but still getting unfortunately app has stopped why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial problem is that the mime type is incorrect, it should be `text/plain`, not `plain/text`.  However, this creates more of a generic share `Intent` that will match all kinds of apps from SMS to Dropbox.  If you are truly only wanting to limit the user's options to email clients, you should set up the `Intent` with a different type like so:

```
Intent messageIntent = new Intent();
messageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
messageIntent.setType(“message/rfc822”);
```

Finally, more of a side note, since you are asking an external application to handle this action for you, good practice also dictates that your application should catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` and notify the user of this for cases where the user actually **doesn't** have an app on their device that will handle this request.

Comment: Awesome, did not know that about `"message/rfc822"`.

Comment: @Devunwired whenever i do click on send button it is asking recipient address why? i have already given email address here:: String aEmailList[] = { "udhikriman@gmail.com" };

Answer (score 0):

This is how to have the user send an email:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email@domain.com");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Default email text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email via:"));
```

Comment: Yeah it looks fine, see my answer. You may need `Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email via:")`. Also the mime-type should be "plain/text".

Comment: whenever i do click on send button it is asking recipient address why? i have already given email address here:: String aEmailList[] = { "udhikriman@gmail.com" };

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9097251/832776

Also you may want to remove your email address...

Comment: what it does : message/rfc822